# Want to get user from Microsoft Office 365 Management API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365, azure-management-api

I have created an App on https://portal.azure.com/ and have received all the credentials like `client-id`, `redirect_url` etc.

When I try to log in using the following url with my credentials:

```
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanage.office.com&client_id={xxxxxxxxxxx}&redirect_uri={xxxxxxxxxxxxx}
```

I get a screen saying:

> Permission requested Accept for your orghanisation'

[image]

here, when I press the ACCEPT button. It does not redirect to the respective url.

Comment: what's the question?? Press Accept and continue the process

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish sir, the problem is that the ACCEPT button does not redirect us to anywhere, nothing happens on clicking the ACCEPT button, we have mentioned the problem at the bottom.

Comment: When you press the "accept" button, your `redirect_uri` is called.Your `redirect_uri` will exchange the `code` for credentials.  Your code (web server) is responsible for displaying something. Study how OAuth 2 Flows work. There are many examples available.

Comment: After you click on the "Accept", what will happen? Please add more details.